# Install themeforest theme in wordpress.com

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress.com

I bought the themeforest.net wordpress theme. I created a blog at wordpress. How to import themeforest theme to wordpress.com

Do I need to find the hosting provider, install wordpress on it and then upload the themeforest theme there?

I want to install the themeforest theme at wordpress.com, not at the hosting. Please let me know if it's possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://en.support.wordpress.com/themes/adding-new-themes/

"Because of the way WordPress.com’s technical infrastructure is designed, we are not able to support uploading of custom WordPress themes on our service."

"You can move your WordPress.com blog to **a web host that allows editing and uploading of completely custom themes**. You can find suitable hosts here."

Older blog post, but im sure it still applies.
Doesn't look like it's an option. Looks like you need your own hosting.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to find a hosting provider,
>   install wordpress on it and then
>   upload the themeforest theme there?

Yes.

> I want to install the themeforest
>   theme at wordpress.com, not at the
>   hosting. Please let me know if it's
>   possible

No.

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Hosting_WordPress