# Page templates, wordpress, without FTP

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a .wordpress.com blog that would like to get some custom page templates, I understand how how to write page templates, but, I don't understand how to get the template onto whatever.wordpress.com without FTP access!

EDIT: I don't want themes, I need to basically make a price form, where users select options, and based on options the price of a product increases, and this price is emailed to the user. I sort of guessed I could use page templates for this, but, I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty much out of luck for the wordpress.com free feature. For full custom template options, you will need to host your own word press site. Or alternatively, choose a good theme and customize the css / etc, as part of its 'premium' feature:

http://en.wordpress.com/products/

**EDIT:** side notes

> Hosting plans are cheap anyway for wordpress blogs these days, LOL most major host allows it to be pre-installed as you purchase your web-space. At less then US$10 per month, it ain't that bad. Probably cheaper then 'premium' with alot more freedom. (=X unless you already got a really popular bog)

Additionally, wordpress admin interface itself, comes with a built in theme / file editor (if you host it on your own). That allows you to edit the theme / PHP / css files. Though it may lack syntax highlighting, that can be easily remedied with plug-ins.

Comment: I'm not doing themes, I need to do use PHP to send an email, and javascript to fill out the email.

Comment: No PHP on wordpress.com and no javascript. It's what pico.creator wrote. Check for the paid upgrades if there is anyhting for you that fits. But probably you still won't be able until you go to wordpress.com VIP hosting.

Comment: Hosting plans are cheap anyway for wordpress blogs these days, LOL most major host allows it to be pre-installed as you purchase your web-space. At less then US$10 per month, it ain't that bad. Probably cheaper then 'premium' with alot more freedom.

Answer (score 1):

[Install themeforest theme in wordpress.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298820/install-themeforest-theme-in-wordpress-com/) (similar question)

You can't install custom templates on a wordpress.com blog, only choose whatever is there.
You need your own hosting to be able to install custom themes.